# Don't set application for protocol

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

### 1. Summary

I don't find, how I can set application for `litecoin:` protocol in Firefox.

---

### 2. Settings

For example, I open `Example.html` file in Firefox:

```html
<a href="litecoin:LLVvhNKGMLGHa8QmeRrBsjZUBjSpQMjUkP">Sasha link</a>
```

I use [**Litecoin URI**](https://electrum-ltc.org/litecoin_URIs.html).

---

### 3. Expected behavior

If I click to `Sasha Link` in fresh Firefox version without plugins and user settings, I get popup:

[image: Fresh]

I select my application for Litecoin link → I successful open my link.

---

### 4. Actual behavior

If I click to `Sasha Link` in my Firefox.

[image: File not found]

> File not found
>   Firefox can’t find the file at litecoin:LLVvhNKGMLGHa8QmeRrBsjZUBjSpQMjUkP.
>   Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
>   Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.

I reproduce the problem in a Firefox Safe Mode.

---

### 5. Not helped

1. I make actions of [**this manual**](http://scadsdnd.ddns.net/techwiki/doku.php?id=browsers:firefox_custom_protocol). `about:config` → I set value `false` for `network.protocol-handler.expose-all` → I click to Sasha Link → nothing occurs. Also, nothing occurs in Firebug console.
2. I don't find in Google and Mozilla addons site extension for set application for custom protocol.

---

### 6. Questions

1. How I can determine the cause, why I get unexpected behavior?
2. Is a other way for set application for a protocol?

---

### 7. Do not offer

1. Please, do not offer reinstall Firefox. I don't want, that reinstall browser for each small bag — a nice idea.

---

### 8. Environment

**Operating system and version:**
Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 64-bit EN
**Firefox:**
52.0.1